# Update sheet contents while running a looping Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet which has a number of sheets which are cycled through using a Macro to make it appear like a slide show. This information is then projected onto a TV.

```
Sub Cycle()
  On Error GoTo exit_
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
    
    Do
    Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    
    Sheets("Sheet 2").Select
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    
    Sheets("Sheet 3").Select
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) 

  Loop
exit_:
End Sub
```

This spreadsheet is stored on MS Teams so that others may update the data in this spreadsheet.
The problem is that when the macro is running and new data is entered into a cell it will not display this updated cell.

I have tried using screenupdate to no avail

Comment: *This spreadsheet is stored on MS Teams* - is this OneDrive or Sharepoint? How could you store anything on MSTeams? Does it have its own storage area?

Comment: Welcome user23463403! Take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: Teams uses SharePoint for document storage